# Reflection, inheritance, and java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm wondering how does reflection on inherited classes work?  It appears that the methods are not reflectively available in my superclasses constructor.

If I have a subclass "horse" of "animal", is it possible to access the methods of "horse" using reflection when I am in the "animal" superclasse's constructor? It appears not.

Comment: yes you can. What makes you say -"it appears not" ? Just use the Reflection API to load the `Horse` class, create a new instance and call its methods. But can you tell us a bit more why you want this sort of approach ?

Comment: You might want to specify "without calling `setAccessible`. Not that there is much point in using reflection on fields and non-public methods without `setAccessible`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SuperClass constructor is always run before the child class's. So the instance of child class is never in ready state to be used as such.

Comment: +1: Good point. The methods are available but the instance is unlikely to be in a state when those methods can be used.

Comment: @saury , indeed the instance of subclass *associated with current Superclass* is not in a ready state to be called in the superclass ctr , but the question asks about the possibility of calling the Subclass ctr in general, using Reflection - which is quite possible , right ?

Answer (score 2):

Is it not possible, because constructor body of animal is invoked before body of constructor horse. Horse 'part' of object doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

A superclass's ctor (or anything else, really) shouldn't be accessing sub-class-specific methods; the superclass should not know anything about classes that derive from it.

For that matter, superclasses shouldn't call methods defined by subclasses in its ctor because the object hasn't been initialized yet. [Here's some discussion regarding that, with examples.](http://benpryor.com/blog/2008/01/02/dont-call-subclass-methods-from-a-superclass-constructor/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instance of a Horse, it doesn't matter where you are (including int he Animal constructor) you can access all the methods/fields of that instance.

However, if you are in a plain Animal or some other subclass, you can't access methods/fields of Horse because its not a Horse.

Comment: I think the OP is asking something else : can the ctr/methods of subclass be called from superclass ctr *using Reflection* ? I would say - Yes why not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Via the reflection API you can access the methods of a subclass (or any class) if you're in a constructor. In terms of good practice, then no since an animal is not a horse.

Comment: Really... Even inside the superclass constructor without knowing the subclass instance?

Comment: Accessing the methods of another class is independent of existing instances. You can retrieve the methods for a class via the Class.getMethod or Class.getMethods methods. Once you have the method retrieved you can invoke it via the Method.invoke  method using the constructors this reference as the obj argument. This would almost certainly be wrong, but doable, likely resulting in some exception being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to realize is the way that java loads classes : first the superclass is loaded, and then the subclasses.

if you need to access methods that are specific to the subclass, you will have to find another methodology.

One strategy , for example, would to embed some of the contract which your subclass is fulfilling in the superclass using interfaces or inheritance....